# foreach to linq expression help needed

Tags: c#, linq

having some trouble writing the following code to some nicer/less lines :)

any one have the good solution?

```
//custom implementation for popular filters
        var popularFilter = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var car in allFilteredCars)
        {
            foreach (var offering in car.Offerings)
            {
                if (popularFilter.ContainsKey(offering))
                    popularFilter[offering] = popularFilter[offering] + 1;
                else
                    popularFilter.Add(offering, 1);
            }
        }

        categories.Add(new Category
        {
            Name = "popular",
            Code = "popular",
            Values = popularFilter.Select(p => new Value
            {
                Code = p.Key,
                Name = p.Key,
                Count = p.Value
            }).ToList()
        });
```

If it is possible i want i directly to add it in the `categories` list.

`car.offerings` = `list<string>`

so basicly something like:

```
Categories.Add(allFilteredCars.SelectMany(
 c => c.Offerings.Select(
                o => new {
              something magical here}
  .Select(a => 
     new Category{
         code.. etc etc..}
  ));
```

Comment: Leave the code as is... Sometimes it is better to be less "smart" and more "readable".

Comment: Looks quite clean already. You could try with a groupby offering.

Comment: I think your code above looks much better than LINQ train you are trying to interpret

Comment: as the comments above state, your solution as is is a good one. The desire to compress code is understandable, but it is sometimes better to stick with bigger code. LINQ will not give you performance boosts in comparison to your current implementation, while it does confuse due to it's un-orderlyness

Comment: I'm going to give a dissenting opinion.  The code you have is good if you need a dictionary, but you don't.  Dictionaries are good for doing look-ups, but here you end up iterating on it instead.  It's sole purpose is just to be used for grouping the values so they can be counted.  I agree that many times converting code to Linq can result in harder to understand code, but I don't think this is one of those times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just want to do a `SelectMany` to get the offerings, then group them and select the `Count`.

```
categories.Add(new Category
{
    Name = "popular",
    Code = "popular",
    Values = allFilteredCars.SelectMany(c => c.Offerings)
        .GroupBy(o => o)
        .Select(grp => new Value
        {
            Code = grp.Key,
            Name = grp.Key,
            Count = grp.Count()
        }).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your non linq code already looks quite fine.
You can create your dictionary with linq by using a GroupBy & ToDictionary:

```
var dictionary = offerings
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```